# Let $A$ be an $n\times n $ symmetric matrix with $A^2=A$. What is the relationship between the null space of $A $ and the column space of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix which satisfies $A^2=A$. What is the relationship between the null space of $A$ and the column space of $A$?

$A^{2}x=Ax=0$

Let's suppose that $Ax=b$.

Therefore, $A^{2}x=A(A(x))=A(b)=b$. 
Therefore, $ A$ is either the identity matrix or the zero matrix.
Either way, the null space is perpendicular to the column space.

Is my solution correct? If not, can you please guide me to the right solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that $A$ is either the identity matrix or the zero matrix?

Comment: Look up "Idempotent Matrix"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is an  projection which is orthogonal, because of being symmetric. It is not either the identity or the zero matrix. For example,
$$ A = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right) $$
verifies the conditions. The kernel (null space) is indeed perpendicular to the image (column space) but you should possibly prove this in your exercise?

Some details: $z\in \ker A$ means that for every $x \in H$ (our Hilbert space) we have (using $A=A^T$):
$$ 0 = x^T A z = z^T A^T x = z^T A x$$ 
which is equivalent to $z\perp {\rm im} A$. So $\ker A = ({\rm im} A)^\perp$. Being in finite dimensions ${\rm im} A$ is closed so also ${\rm im A} = (\ker A)^\perp$. The previous only uses $A=A^T$.

From $A^2=A$ you get the additional information that ${\rm im} A = \ker (1-A)$ and ${\rm im} (1-A) = \ker A$. Any vector $x\in H$ has the orthogonal decomposition: $x= Ax + (1-A)x$.

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how to prove this? Thanks!

Comment: Is the following solution alright? Let y be a vector in the null space of A such that Ay=0. Let Ax exist in the column space of A such that Ax=b. So A^2xy=Axy=(A transpose)xy=by=0 since the row space of A is perpendicular to the null space of A.

Comment: You are on the right track but should be careful with how you write it down. I have added some details.

Comment: Maybe it suffices to note that the image of $A$ is the eigenspace of eigenvalue $1$?